# SMint template and Slider don't work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been trying to combine SMINT template and BJQS slider together. My goal is to put slider to the right of "SMINT Demo Page/n Something Something Something", example how SMINT looks like is here: http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/demo/

To make the slider works, I need to put these lines into smint template:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#banner-fade').bjqs({
    'height' : 320,
    'width' : 620,
    'responsive' : true
});
});
```

I want to put the above mentioned jQuery code to MY created slider.js file, but the slider doesn't even show up and it just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? As far as I know $(document).ready(); is supposed to be only written once. Can also someone explain how should I prioritise script files: what goes first in head bjqs script or smint?

So far SMINT template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="bjqs.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="bjqs.css" />

 // ^^^^ necessary lines for BJQS

<script src="slider.js"></script>

// ^^^ my created .js file that I want to have the BJQS code in.

<link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.smint.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.subMenu').smint({
            'scrollSpeed' : 1000
        });
        // I tried putting here $('#banner-fade').bjqs({ bla bla
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap ">
<div class="section sTop">
        <div class="inner">
            <h1 class="title">SMINT Demo Page</h1>
            <h2 class="subtitle">Something something something</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="my-slideshow">
        <ul class="bjqs">
            <li img src="img/banner01.jpg"> </li>
            <li img src="img/banner02.jpg"> </li>
            <li img src="img/banner03.jpg"> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope my question is clear. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: TypeError: $(...).bjqs is not a function slider.js:4
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. index.html
TypeError: $(...).position(...) is null

Comment: This states that your `bjqs` script wasn't loaded by the time slider.js ran. Have you tried using plugins separately? Does it work?

Comment: I finally made it work. I put those call-lines of bjqs (not sure how to call them, links maybe?) after smint. And the javascript code I put after the list of images, which I found a bit odd. At least I see it now. One more question, how do I put it to the right of the page? Should I use padding or alignment?